# How to query for an executed smart contract in db-sync?

Tags: wallet, cardano-db-sync

If any DApp allows the user to connect their wallet and make use of a given smart contract, how can I most efficiently find that through queries in db-sync? Select on an address associated with the smart contract address? Search for assets or wallets involved in the smart contract's execution?

So:
Smart Contract X is executed on behalf of connected wallet Y, involving assets A, B & C.

How to find this..as a tx_out?

Thank you!